# Opening links from client applications takes at least 60 seconds

Tags: browser, links

Web browsers need at least 60 seconds to open links when I click on one in my client application (e.g. Notepad++, Keepass, Outlook or Excel). I have tried to set a different default web browser, but it shows the same behaviour.

I also checked the event viewer, but found nothing helpful.

My system is a fresh installed Windows 10 Pro x64 with a new i7 8700k on a Gigabyte Aorus 5.

Do you have any idea what the problem could be or where I can begin to troubleshoot?

Comment: Is that issue even if the browser is already open, before you click the link?

Comment: Yes, the browser is already open

Comment: See if Task Manager (or Process Explorer) shows some process starting or using more CPU time when you click on the link. Also check browser add-ons (e.g. by staring in Safe mode, with all disabled). Could it be an AV Web check, looking up the sites safety?

Comment: Thank you Pippik, with your help i could find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help from DrMoishe Pippik i could fix the issue. The delay was caused by the State Repository Service.

I had to reinstall the built-in apps and repair Edge as described here.
http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/state-repository-service-high-cpu-usage-windows-10-fall-creators-update/

First, I executed this command as admin.

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode 
-Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Then i repaired Edge in the Settings under "Apps & Features".