# Windows 10 Browser taking abnormally long to open external URLs

Tags: google-chrome, browser, routing, microsoft-edge, windows-10-v1703

I just bought a new Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro 15.6" laptop and have a fresh Windows 10 Pro installation.

When I try to open a URL from an external application, for instance a link on Skype or inside a PDF document, my browser does not respond immediately. About a minute later, the URL will randomly load up in my browser.

If I copy and paste that same URL to my browser manually, it loads up immediately.

I'm using Chrome but this problem persists regardless of what I change my default browser to.

I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem could be. Please help.

Comment: Does it happen only when from skype or is it true on other programs too? If true on others, what are some examples of those?

Comment: It happens on every application that isn't the browser. I've tested by trying to open https://www.google.com from multiple programs, e.g. Adobe Acrobat DC, Notepad++, Discord, Visual Studio, etc

Comment: How long is "abnormally long"? and how long is "normal"?

Comment: "Abnormally long" was over 60 seconds. "Normal" is in the order of milliseconds. Thanks for humoring me. I managed to solve the problem!

Comment: You should post your answer below then and then accept it in 2 days. Glad you found a solution though :)

Comment: I edited the question to include the answer. Is it customary to also post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes posting as an answer is much better. Please remove it from your question, post as an answer , then accept in 2 days

Comment: ah, thank you - I wasn't sure of etiquette on this site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** I just solved the problem thanks to [ra213](https://superuser.com/users/782379/ra213)'s post on [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1271181/opening-links-from-client-applications-takes-at-least-60-seconds?rq=1). As stated on [this site](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/state-repository-service-high-cpu-usage-windows-10-fall-creators-update/) the issue was with the Service Host: State Repository Service after the Windows 10 Creator's Update. I was able to solve the issue by launching PowerShell as administrator and running the following command:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

This registered all standard apps and fixed my problem. I can now open links immediately from other applications.